# How do I attach calculated properties or methods to collections in Astro?

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

I'm using Astro with strict type checking.

I have a collection called "portfolio" and I have a couple of conventions for where images are stored for my portfolio. It goes something like:

- If portfolioEntry.type = "website" then

  - desktopScreenshot = "@content/portfolio/_img/${portfolioEntry.slug}-desktop.png"
  - tabletScreenshot = "@content/portfolio/_img/${portfolioEntry.slug}-tablet.png"
- Etc.

Is there any way to attach logic like this to collection entries? It would be great if I was able to:

```js
let entry = getEntry("portfolio", "foo-2023");

console.log(entry.thumbnail());
```

Where `thumbnail()` is a function that I've attached to the collection, like a method on a class.

Is there currently any way to achieve this?

---

What I'm doing currently is:

```js
function resolvePortfolioThumbnail(entry: any): ImageMetadata {
    // ...
}
```

Which is annoying since I'm not getting any type checking, and in spite of my best effort I couldn't find any way to refer to the portfolio collection type in my function signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type your `resolve` helper using Astro’s `CollectionEntry` type:

```
import type { CollectionEntry } from 'astro:content';

function resolvePortfolioThumbnail(entry: CollectionEntry<'portfolio'>): ImageMetadata {
    // ...
}
```

There’s no built-in way to automatically do this when calling `getEntry()`, but you could create a method you use instead:

```
import type { ImageMetadata } from 'astro';
import { getEntry, type CollectionEntry } from 'astro:content';

async function getPortfolioEntry(slug: CollectionEntry<'portfolio'>['slug']) {
  const entry = await getEntry("portfolio", slug);
  return {
    ...entry,
    thumbnail(): ImageMetadata {
      // ...
    },
  };
}
```